# SSR Cache issue 3.x Version

Tags: server-side-rendering, spartacus-storefront

We have one peculiar issue in SSR rendering. Pages are being served from cache layer from second time in SSR rendering. We want to disable this for certain use cases. E.g If we change the product name in back office and try to access the product in storefront first time we get 301. But next time we get 200. So we always wanted to get 301 when product name gets changed/removed. We tried setting via header this.response.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); But it didn't work. Can you please help us with this?  #help

Answer (score 0):

Disabling cache only for certain scenarios is not supported in Spartacus SSR optimization engine, and you would have to write a custom logic to support it.

For 5.0+ version we can consider to make the "return from cache on second render" feature optional. Can you please create a ticket for that on GitHub?

As a side note, it seems like you're using SSR as a live server, which is not recommended. We recommend putting SSR servers / nodes behind a CDN. If CDN caches 301, the requests hitting the CDN will always get 301.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But we can achieve this by writing custom logic? You mean in server.ts file? Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: I meant that you can extend the `OptimizedSsrEngine` and override the appropriate methods / writing custom logic.

Comment: If by "cache layer" (from your question) you mean the`cache` option in optimization engine, then you can try to change this behavior:https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/release/3.4.x/core-libs/setup/ssr/optimized-engine/optimized-ssr-engine.ts#L247.

Again, it's recommended to disable the `cache` option altogether, and have a CDN in front of SSR nodes. After making a change in the back-office, you have to invalidate CDN's cache, and trigger caching again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We will try move that into CDN.Meanwhile I tried disabling cache completely. Still it didn't work.  I added this inside decorateExpressEngine : optimizationOptions: SsrOptimizationOptions | null = {
    concurrency: 20,
    timeout: 3000,
    cache: false,
  }